# How to present a video and only rotate it?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, video, mpmovieplayercontroller

what I want to do is pretty simple.

I have a `UIViewController` (portrait only!) and inside its view I want to display a video (in a part of the view). Then I want to add a `UIButton` that enables the user to display the video fullscreen.
When the video is in fullscreen, I want the video to follow the orientation of the device but not the `UIViewController` presenting the video so that if the user is in landscape and quit the fullscreen mode, the `UIViewController` should be in portrait !
I also want to add custom controls when the video is in fullscreen.

Do you have any idea how I should proceed ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had done this before. Just `setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI/2)`

```
- (void)rotateVideoToLandscape {

    int64_t delayInSeconds = 0.5;
    dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC);
    dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight];
    });

    // Before rotate the video, exchange the width & height for a better user-experience.
    [self.view setBounds:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.height, self.view.width)];
    [self.view setCenter:CGPointMake(self.view.width/2, self.view.height/2)];
    [self.view setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI/2)];

    CGRect playerRect = self.view.bounds;
    // Do something needed.
    self.moviePlayerController.view.frame = playerRect;
}
```